# Using results from ODEProblem while it is running

Tags: julia, simulation, differential-equations, differentialequations.jl

I’m currently studying the documentation of [DifferentialEquations.jl](https://github.com/JuliaDiffEq/DifferentialEquations.jl) and trying to port my older computational neuroscience codes for using it instead of my own, less elegant and performant, ODE solvers. While doing this, I stumbled upon the following question: is it possible to access and use the results returned from the solver as soon as the current step is returned (instead of waiting for the problem to finish)?

I’m looking for a way to e.g. plot in real-time the voltage levels of a simulated neuron, which seems like a simple enough task and one that’s probably trivial to do using already existing Julia packages but I can’t figure out how. Does it have to do anything with callbacks? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Plots.jl doesn't seem to be animating for me right now, but I'll show you the steps anyways. Yes, you can use a `DiscreteCallback` for this. If you make `condition(u,t,integrator)=true` then the `affect!` is called every step, and you could do that.

But, I think using the integrator interface is perfect for this case. Let me show you an example of this. Take the 2D problem from the tutorial:

```
using DifferentialEquations
using Plots
A  = [1. 0  0 -5
      4 -2  4 -3
     -4  0  0  1
      5 -2  2  3]
u0 = rand(4,2)
tspan = (0.0,1.0)
f(u,p,t) = A*u
prob = ODEProblem(f,u0,tspan)
```

Now instead of using `solve`, use `init` to get an `integrator` out.

```
integrator = init(prob,Tsit5())
```

The integrator interface is defined in full [at its documentation page](http://diffeq.sciml.ai/latest/basics/integrator.html), but the basic usage is that you can step using `step!`. If you put that in a loop and keep stepping then that's essentially what `solve` does. But it also has the iterator interface, so if you do something like `for integ in integrator` then inside of the for loop `integ` will be the current state of the integrator, with values `integ.u` at time point `integ.t`. It also has all sorts of things like a plot recipe for intermediate interpolation `integ(t)` (this is true even when `dense=false` because it's free and doesn't require extra saving allocations, so feel free to use it).

So, you can do

```
p = plot(integrator,markersize=0,legend=false,xlims=tspan)
anim = @animate for integ in integrator
    plot!(p,integrator,lw=3)
end
plot(p)
gif(anim, "test.gif", fps = 2)
```

and Plots.jl will give you the animated gif that adds the current interval at each step. Here's what the end plot looks like:

[image]

It colored differently in each step because it was a different plot, so you can see how it continued. Of course, you can do anything inside of that loop, or if you want more control you can manually `step!(integrator)` as necessary.

Comment: Great answer, as always!

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. The integrator interface does indeed seem to provide me with everything I need at this point.